# Android test project cannot find app classes

Tags: android, eclipse, junit

I have an Android app that I am trying to test using JUnit in Eclipse. I created an Android Test project and added some tests, but when I try to run the tests on my device, every test fails with a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on the class I am trying to test.

I found some similar questions, but nothing quite that same as my issue. The closest one is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545518/noclassdeffounderror-while-executing-android-junit-test), but this user is using Maven and figured out a workaround using this. I am not using Maven.

Here is some of the output from LogCat:

```
03-26 13:36:05.281: I/TestRunner(8380): started: testValueOf(com.evertz.android.vlpro.unit.SeverityTest)
03-26 13:36:05.281: I/TestRunner(8380): failed: testValueOf(com.evertz.android.vlpro.unit.SeverityTest)
03-26 13:36:05.281: I/TestRunner(8380): ----- begin exception -----
03-26 13:36:05.281: I/TestRunner(8380): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.evertz.android.vlpro.Severity
03-26 13:36:05.281: I/TestRunner(8380):     at com.evertz.android.vlpro.unit.SeverityTest.testValueOf(SeverityTest.java:19)
03-26 13:36:05.281: I/TestRunner(8380):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 13:36:05.281: I/TestRunner(8380):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-26 13:36:05.281: I/TestRunner(8380):     at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
03-26 13:36:05.281: I/TestRunner(8380):     at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
03-26 13:36:05.281: I/TestRunner(8380):     at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:115)
03-26 13:36:05.281: I/TestRunner(8380):     at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:133)
03-26 13:36:05.281: I/TestRunner(8380):     at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:118)
03-26 13:36:05.281: I/TestRunner(8380):     at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
03-26 13:36:05.281: I/TestRunner(8380):     at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
03-26 13:36:05.281: I/TestRunner(8380):     at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
03-26 13:36:05.281: I/TestRunner(8380):     at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
03-26 13:36:05.281: I/TestRunner(8380):     at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1661)
03-26 13:36:05.281: I/TestRunner(8380): ----- end exception -----
03-26 13:36:05.281: I/TestRunner(8380): finished: testValueOf(com.evertz.android.vlpro.unit.SeverityTest)
```

I have other Android projects with JUnit tests that work just fine. Here is a brief summary:

- Utils: An Android library project with several utility classes copied from my existing Java code base and Android-ified.
- UtilsTest: Corresponding unit tests for classes in the Utils project. Has a reference to easymock.jar. These tests run perfectly fine on the device.
- AppOne: A simple Android app with no dependencies to Utils, EasyMock, or anything else.
- AppOneTest: Unit tests for AppOne classes. These tests run OK as well.
- AppTwo: An Android app with a dependency to the Utils library project.
- AppTwoTest: Unit tests for AppTwo classes. Has depedencies to Utils and EasyMock. All of these tests fail as described above (can't find class under test).

All of the test classes are using JUnit3 semantics (extend TestCase, no annotations, etc). None of the classes under test are Activity-based (yet). I am just testing support classes for now, and these have only minor references to Android SDK classes (e.g. android.util.Log, android.graphics.Color).

I thought that having external dependencies might be causing problems somehow, so I tried adding some (unnecessary) calls to Utils classes in AppOne and AppOneTest, but these tests still worked. I also tried deleting all the tests from AppTwoTest except for one that doesn't refer to Utils or EasyMock (the SeverityTest class from the LogCat output), and this still failed.

I tried clean builds, restarting Eclipse, deleting and recreating the AppTwoTest project, and nothing seems to work. Any ideas on what could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the manifest of the test app, it should contain the following:

1. Package definition for the test code
2. Uses-sdk that is appropriate for your app
3. uses-library that links in the test runner
4. Instrumentation with link to the app code

   ```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.test"      <!-- package of the test code -->
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="8"
       android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

   <instrumentation
       android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
       android:targetPackage="com.example.app" />      <!-- package of the app code -->

   <application android:allowBackup="false">
       <!-- linkage for the test runner -->
       <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />     
   </application>
   ```

Comment: This fixed it. I had the wrong instrumentation target package (was using package of test project instead of app). I thought I checked this, but I guess I missed it. Thank you!

Comment: Is this the recommended approach with the new Gradle build system?